# Rails Nokogiri XML parsing working locally, not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, heroku, nokogiri

I have the following script running in my rails app.  When it runs locally, it parses all of the courses correctly (9673 results) but when I push it to Heroku, it returns exactly 2x this number (19346 results).  Any ideas?  Are there possible Heroku performance limitations that could be causing the cycle to repeat itself?

```ruby
# Pulls all course data for specified year, based on subject list
subjectdoc= Nokogiri.XML(open("https://courseroster.reg.cornell.edu/courses/roster/SP15/xml/"))
# Reads each subject and stores it in local variable prefix
subjectdoc.xpath("//subject/@subject").each do |prefix|
  # Link to course pages, substituting in prefix in URL
  classdoc= Nokogiri.XML(open("https://courseroster.reg.cornell.edu/courses/roster/SP15/#{prefix}/xml/"))
  # Reads each course and stores listed vars
  classdoc.xpath("/courses/course").each do |course|
    num = course["catalog_nbr"] || "Not provided"
    subj = course["subject"]    || "Not provided"
    title = (course.at("course_title/text()") || "Not provided").to_s
    cid = (course.at("sections/section/@class_number") || "Not provided").to_s
    inst = (course.at("sections/section/meeting/instructors/instructor/text()") || "Not provided").to_s
    # Creates a cornell class in Cornellclasses table
    Cornellclass.create(:prefix => subj, :coursenumber => num, :instructor => inst, :title => title, :courseid => cid)
  end
end
```

Comment: A fresh Heroku app stops at 9673 for me.

Comment: Guess: you have two copies of the app running, or two instances of the file, or two services, or some such. To test this, add something to another database with a timestamp once for each time you run this script.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix?